# Android Studio - Install failed. Installation failed <a href='rerun'>Rerun</a>

Tags: android, android-studio

I am unable to run my android project on any android device.

I am getting error on android studio. My project is building and compiling without any error.

Attaching [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4ESS.png)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sometimes, the actual error message shows up in IDE (internal) Fatal Errors, accessible at the bottom right of the Android Studio IDE (should be a red circle with an exclamation mark within).

When it happened for me, I found out through Fatal Errors that my target device was out of space.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem and turned out I had not enough space.

Answer (score 12):

1. Close emulator.
2. Wipe data in AVD Manager for a particular emulator.

[image]

Comment: I am facing this issue on android devices. I tried on Samsung S7 and Nexus 6

Answer (score 2):

Wiping emulator may help, but what if I'm using physical, configured for use device? This bug is weird and a bit random... for me restarting IDE and device helped, also used `Android Studio -> Files -> Invalidate Caches / Restart` and manual killing/restarting daemon with `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server` commands

also: note that some devices have additional toggles to turn on for developing purposes, e.g. Xiaomi have separated option in dev prefs for allowing installing apks through USB, USB debugging turned on isn't sufficient

Comment: With Xiaomi Mi 8 Lite i have to toggle the option 'Install through USB'

Answer (score 2):

> Blockquote

In my device don't  have efficient space .After remove some apps this error  solved.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this issue on the Android Emulator (last available version, HAXM 7.5.1) installing a project with API 28 under AS 3.4.1 (**a simple run**, **not a debug**!). The solution was to **set check** to

**File -> Settings -> Debugger -> Allow unsigned requests** checkbox.

**UPDATE 28/07/2019**
The reason was an insufficient internal memory of API 28 Emulator in my case. The error have disappeared after adding extra space.

Comment: issue still occurs

Comment: @Indrek Kõue Try to change emulator. I have this problem on the emulator with API 28 only. Emulator with API 27 works fine...

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error without any other build/compilation error after editing my AndroidManifest.xml and accidentally leaving a meta-data tag without a corresponding android:value or android:resource attribute. Check your manifest for similar errors

Wrong:

```
<meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"/>
```

Right

```
<meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" android:resource="@xml/device_filter"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using physical device, go to settings/developer options in your device and turn on "Install via USB" option. This will allow installation via USB.